# How to give links of videos after clicking the item in an list view

Tags: java, android

I have to give all the links previously before the functionaily starts,if I click the item in `ListView` ,it  has to go to that video link, now I gave the link in holder of `ListView` , it will not looking good,if I click the first item in `ListView` ,it will take the first link like that respective manner I need.

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main1);

            ArrayList<Recipedetails1> image_details = GetSearchResults();

            final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV1_main);
            lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter1(this, image_details));

            lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                    Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Recipedetails1 obj_itemDetails = (Recipedetails1)o;
                    final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(((Recipedetails1) o).getUrlWiki()));
                      startActivity(i);
} 
            });
        }

        private ArrayList<Recipedetails1> GetSearchResults(){
            ArrayList<Recipedetails1> results = new ArrayList<Recipedetails1>();

            Recipedetails1 item_details = new Recipedetails1();
            item_details.setName1("Vegterian");
            item_details.setItemDescription1("Recipes made by raw materials");
            item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber1(1);
            results.add(item_details);

            item_details = new Recipedetails1();
            item_details.setName1("Non-Vegterian");
            item_details.setItemDescription1("Flesh of sweet animals");
            item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber1(2);
            results.add(item_details);

            item_details = new Recipedetails1();
            item_details.setName1("Pickels");
            item_details.setItemDescription1("Touchable dish  by Homemade");
            item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber1(3);
            results.add(item_details);

            item_details = new Recipedetails1();
            item_details.setName1("Soups");
            item_details.setItemDescription1("Startup for our food");
            item_details.setUrlWiki("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_r0mFvMSfU");
            item_details.setImageNumber1(4);
            results.add(item_details);




            return results;
        }
```

actually I don't need like this manner because it's not looking good,I want that my link not shown,it has to work after the click the item in an ListView ,actually in my code,after clicking the item it will goes,but it will takes from my holder link is this any other way to giving link.this code method is not looking good,I dont need my holder wants to show my link too

Comment: also post custom adapter code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/E1VzY2GE see this link for that one,actually i dont want to give my link in holder of item in an list view,i want only give the link after clicking item in an list view

Comment: then why u are adding Link in ListView just comment holder.recipeLinkWiki from AdapterView

Comment: hmmm ok i will do that one that is enough for my question

Comment: have u try it is it working or not ?

Comment: checking dude just wait i will tel you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a link from `image_details` array list by click position. `image_details.get(position).getUrlWiki();`

Use it like this :

```
ArrayList<Recipedetails1> image_details;

@Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

        image_details = GetSearchResults();

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV1_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter1(this, image_details));

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                //int pos = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String link = image_details.get(position).getUrlWiki();
                final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link));
                  startActivity(i);


} 


 });
    }
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/E1VzY2GE dude i think u are not getting my point,in my previous code also if i click the item it has to go to their respective video,but what i gave is i put my links in holder and then only it will takes the geturlwiki,now what i need is i dont want to do like that,i want all the links in an array format,have to take the link as per the order,you can see my codes in that link

Comment: if I understand you, you don't want to show link in list view. If this right then use my answer an remove `holder.txt_itemDescription1` from your adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Right now my code is working,i removed holder of url wiki in my list adapter,now its looking good and working alos, i comment this line //holder.recipeLinkWiki.setText(itemDetailsrrayList1.get(position).getUrlWiki());